# Error in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

When I run my angularjs application, I get the following error message:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22safeHtml()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%7D%22%5D%2C%5B%22safeHtml()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%7D%22%5D%2C%5B%22safeHtml()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%7D%22%5D%2C%5B%22safeHtml()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%7D%22%5D%2C%5B%22safeHtml()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%7D%22%5D%5D
```

Here is my controller:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);

gameApp.service('link', function() {
    this.user = false;
});
gameApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});

gameApp.directive('mapActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
           scope.$watch(attr.ngBindHtml, function(value) {
              angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));   
                angular.element('.click').click(function() {
                    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');

                        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
                        {
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }

                });                     
           });
        }
    };
});
function makeTableFrom(str) {
    var k = 1;
    result = "";

    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';

        for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(str[k] == '#') {
                result += '<td id=' + k + '">#</td>';
            }
            else if(str[k] == '&') {
                result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"></td>';
            }

            k++;
        }
        result += '</tr>';
    }
    return result;
}


gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });

});

gameApp.controller("firstPageCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $http.post("lib/action.php", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).success(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                link.user = data;
                console.log(link.user);
                $location.path("/game");
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});


gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location,$sce,$rootScope) {

    $scope.getMonsters = "1";

    $http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.result = makeTableFrom(data);
    });

    $scope.safeHtml = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.result);
    };
    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gameApp">
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="firstPageCtrl">
<div id="layout">
    <div id="topcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="middlecontent">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomcontent">
        {{"AngularJS"}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="js/mastercontroller.js"></script>
</html>
```

Anyone who can help me? I can't find the cause to this error. This error apperad when I added scope.$watch in my directive.

Comment: You haven't pasted your relevant HTML - your index page doesn't include any of the directives in your script. Also, it's useful to say what exactly you want to *do*, because of XY questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would click on Error link, you might see following error:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: 
[["safeHtml(); newVal: {}; oldVal: {}"], 
 ["safeHtml(); newVal: {}; oldVal: {}"],
 ["safeHtml(); newVal: {}; oldVal: {}"],
 ["safeHtml(); newVal: {}; oldVal: {}"],
 ["safeHtml(); newVal: {}; oldVal: {}"]
 ]
```

In basic words you run `watch` on `attr.ngBindHtml`. Into the watch you do any manipulation that causes `attr.ngBindHtml` to change that leads to additional watch cycle.  So Angular blocks you by dropping Exception to avoid infinit loop

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I solve this? Remove scope.$watch?

Comment: @user500468 not at all. try to understand why watcher changes `attr.ngBindHtml`. Try to remove blocks of code under watch till you find the problematic place

Comment: I moved my map-Activity attribute into the div-tag: <div ng-controller="gameCtrl" map-Activity> and that removes the error messages. I think it can have something to do with that my SafeHTML returns html-code formed by 2different of loops in my makeTablrFrom-function?

Comment: @user500468 try to disable everything into the watch.

Comment: BTW, it might be filter: `gameApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});` Verify that you return the same instance. Not new one. It might lead to the same error

Comment: filter output must be the same `filtered` object derived from input.

Comment: I have no clou what you mean. The same filtered object derived from input?